# How can I show/include mouse actions on cypress test video?

Tags: cypress

Cypress can record [video of the tests](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/screenshots-and-videos#Videos) and I want to know is there any existing way(s) to include mouse click action visually?

I am looking into

- (preferably) official way to include the feature: I do not found any option for this in [official doc](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/screenshots-and-videos#Videos)
- (browser level) show visual feedback of mouse click (via plugin or scripts like userscripts)
- run separate program to show mouse click (e.g. KmCaster)

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out? Here is a GitHub discussion I opened on Cypress: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/discussions/22764

Comment: @V.Rubinetti I haven't. I now subscribing the cypress issue.